# how can i draw the figure below in latex

Tags: pdftex, latex3

I want to ask you how i can draw this picture using latex. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Dear Anime. Please provide us with what you've tried up to this point.

Comment: Welcome! Drawing the figure is almost trivial in e.g. `tikz` but presumably this is an XY question, you probably want something else like a title format, or a `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Thank you for your response,in fact i'm a beginner in latex world and i would like the have the code generatorof this figure.

Comment: @Amine: What restrictions do you have in terms of the document class or package that could be used? Any or none?

Comment: I want to use this figure for a test sheet.

Comment: @downvoters While there is arguably ample room for improvement in this question, this is a brand new contributor and a score below -1 may be too harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing the graphics is straightforward except for punching in the texts. The `circledsteps` is particular useful here since it allows us to avoid nesting `tikzpicture`s without introducing a `\savebox`, and it is very flexible.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\colorlet{dred}{red!70!black}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[font=\Huge\bfseries,align=center,rounded corners=3pt,
 path picture={
  \draw[draw=dred,rounded corners=15pt,line width=3mm]
   ([yshift=-1.51mm]path picture bounding box.south west)
   rectangle ([xshift=1.51mm,yshift=1.51mm]path picture bounding box.north east);
 },inner sep=1em] (MPSI){%
    MPSI\\
    \Circled[outer color=dred,fill color=dred,inner color=white,
        inner ysep=12pt,inner xsep=12pt]{4}};
  \node[right=1ex of MPSI.south east,anchor=south west,path picture={
  \draw[draw=dred,rounded corners=12pt,line width=1.5mm]
   ([yshift=-1.5mm]path picture bounding box.north west)
   -- ([yshift=-1.5mm]path picture bounding box.north east)
    ([yshift=1.5mm]path picture bounding box.south west)
   -- ([yshift=1.5mm]path picture bounding box.south east);
    },inner ysep=3mm,font=\large\bfseries,text width=23em,align=center,
    label={[anchor=south east,text=dred,font=\small,
        inner sep=1pt]north east:Lyc\'ee Omar Ibn Al-Khattab -- Meknes}]{
  Devoir Suveill\'e n\textsuperscript{\textsf{o}}8 de Mathematiques\\[1em]
  {\normalsize La Samedi 21 Mars 2020\hfill Dur\'ee: 4 heures}\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.